# A question on Operator of a Banach Space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

For any $x \in X$ where $X$ is a Banach space, is there a non-trivial bounded operator $T \in B(X)$ such that $T(x)=x$?

I mean is there any way to verify the existence of such an operator for any $x \in X$?

Can we construct such an operator in any way?

Comment: bounded operator as continuous linear operator? what about the identity?

Comment: @user251257 Not fair! Identity is a *trivial* example :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, there are plenty: first the identity.

A second idea is to take $f\in X^*$ such that $f(x)\ne 0$. Then define
$$
Tv = \frac{1}{f(x)}f(v) x.
$$
Both of these operators are linear, and can be easily shown to be bounded.

Comment: Thank you @daw. Cleared a doubt i had.